# How can I make an array of frequencies accurately depict a decoded mp3 file?

Tags: java, arrays, byte, mp3, decoding

I am using mp3spi and Triton, and this code will handle exclusively 192kbps mp3 files. 
The problem I am facing is that the first second of hz is mostly made up of exclusively:

0,0,0,0 or 255,255,255,255

I do believe I might not be skipping the header correct, in which case the frequencies are not a true depiction of the mp3 at that specific ms. Does anyone see anything wrong with the way im skipping the header, or how im adding up the bytes to the array?

In other words, I want it so the array at position [0] is equal to the mp3 at position 00:00:00, and the array at position [44100] is equal to the song at exactly 1 second in.

This is the code I use for reading the bytes from the mp3 file, adding it to the arraylist bytes.

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ReadMP3 {


private ArrayList<Integer> bytes = new ArrayList<>();
private AudioFormat decodedFormat;

public ReadMP3() throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException {

    String filename = new ReadFiles().getFile();
    File file = new File(filename);
    AudioInputStream in = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
    AudioInputStream din = null;
    AudioFormat baseFormat = in.getFormat();
    AudioFormat decodedFormat = new 
    AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,
            baseFormat.getSampleRate(),
            16,
            baseFormat.getChannels(),
            baseFormat.getChannels() * 2,
            baseFormat.getSampleRate(),
            false);
    din = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(decodedFormat, in);
    this.decodedFormat = decodedFormat;

    int i = 0;
    while(true){
        int currentByte = din.read();
        if (currentByte == -1) {break;}
        bytes.add(i, currentByte);
        i++;
    }
    din.close();
    in.close();
}
```

This is the second part of my code, where I add 4 bytes to each index of the array, such that array.length / 44100 is equal to the length of the song in seconds. This implies that each array[i][4] is equal to 1hz. 
and array[0][4] up to array[44100][4] is the first second of the song.

```
public class AnalyzeMP3 {


//adds 4 bytes to offset[i], where each i represents 1hz, 
//and 44100hz=1sec

public static int[][] calculate(ReadMP3 mp3) {

    //calculates and prints how long the song is
    double seconds = mp3.getBytes().size() / 
    mp3.getDecodedFormat().getFrameRate() / 4;
    System.out.println("Length of song: " + (int)seconds + "s");

    //adds 4 values to i through the whole song
    int[][] offset  = new int[mp3.getBytes().size()/4][4];
    for(int i = 0; i < mp3.getBytes().size()/4; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            offset[i][j] = mp3.getBytes().get(i+j);
        }
    }

    return offset;
}

}
```

Comment: Do you want an array of **decoded samples** or array of **frequencies** though? Samples are the values of sound data (eg: you can draw a waveform from those numbers). Same decoded sound data (PCM) can be analyzed using FFT algorithm to get frequencies. There's a few strange things in your code/logic so just tell me... (1) in function `calculate (ReadMP3 mp3)` does that _"Length of song"_ really work correctly? (2) Why are you using 2D arrays for reading mp3 bytes? (3) Are you familiar with mp3 header structure (eg: why not calculate song length from header bytes)?

Comment: (4) Don't remove mp3 header since it's needed to correctly decompress (or decode) into sound data (PCM)... **My advice:** Since mp3 is just compression math, leave those bytes unaffected, pass them to a decoder that will extract the sound data (as PCM), then you process that PCM to get frequencies.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time. I want to at first get the decoded samples without the header, such that I can create an accurate waveform and from there apply FFT algorithms. (1) length in audacity = 305,920s,  my calculation = 305.9461. (2) I tried to organize all the bytes of the song into manageable samples. (3) I have read myself up on the header structure, but it seems it doesnt apply to the values I get, I feel a little lost at this part.

Comment: (4) In the class ReadMP3 I decompress the mp3, then in my AnalyzeMP3 class I process that data into samples that accurately portraits each hz in the song at the correct time, and tries to skip the header.

Comment: @Johnsen.Martin I don't see anywhere that you're actually running your file through the codec to get PCM samples.  This idea of skipping the header is nonsense.  You must decode the MP3 in some way if you want to do anything useful with it.

Comment: @Brad It all gets instantiated from my Main class, and `String filename = new ReadFiles().getFile();`, gives me the path to the mp3 file.(this is actually not relevant because I get the decoded PCM samples). I only want to work on the frequencies of the song, with absolutely no connection to the header. If you can tell me the formula to skip the mp3 header from PCM samples, I would update my post with the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Johnsen.Martin Where is it that you think you get decoded PCM samples?  Why do you think decoded PCM samples have anything to do with your MP3 header?

Comment: @Brad `while(true){
        int currentByte = din.read();
        if (currentByte == -1) {break;}
        bytes.add(i, currentByte);
        i++;
    }` Is where i'm getting the decoded PCM samples, and when I do this the header is also added to the array bytes.

Comment: @Brad I added the whole project to my github, if you wanted to accurately see my results just process an mp3 through https://github.com/JohnsenMartin/BeatmapAI Thanks alot.

Comment: To bring more clarity to what im asking, I want to be able to say getFrequency(int offset). where offset is the time in milliseconds and it will then return the corresponding frequencies at offset time in the mp3. Such that I can further process those single ints. That is the only thing I need, and have been stuck at this for over a month.

Comment: @Johnsen.Martin There's no such thing as measurable frequencies at a particular instant in time.  That might be why you're stuck.  You need a chunk of time, with the length relative to the frequencies you wish to observe.  Look up DFT, FFT, and the windowing functions you'll also need.

Comment: @Brad I know that I have to make each ms equal to 44100/1000 frequencies. That is not the problem I have, The problem I have is that I dont know how to calculate the header length from the bytes array and skip it. That is the only problem I have.

Comment: @Johnsen.Martin If this Java class is handling the MP3 codec for you, there will be no header left for you to handle... you'll have straight up PCM samples.  If it doesn't, then you still have to run this data through the codec.  MP3 files don't have a header (well, ID3 may be attached but that's unrelated to MP3 specifically).  It's just a stream with MP3 frames.  Every frame has its own header.  (See also:  https://www.mp3-tech.org/programmer/frame_header.html)

Comment: @Brad From my class i get a bytes array 53968897 in size. (53968897 / 44100) / 4 = 305.946 (the songs length in seconds). This implies that each hz has 4 values and the first 44100 * 4 values is equal to the first second. The problem I have is that the song length in second is wrong, as it is measured to 305.920 seconds in audacity. I also know by hearing that there is no sounds until a second into the song. But even though that is the case, I get a lot of 255, 0, 1, 2 values up to that point. I'm sorry if i'm completely wrong, I major in AI and want to apply these values to a neural network.

Comment: You can't encode an exact file length in an MP3 file.  Also, you have two channels, 16 bits per sample per channel, so make sure you are splitting those and treating them separately if appropriate.  Also, these 16 bit values are signed, so it makes perfect sense what you're seeing.

Comment: @Brad ahh thats good to hear, that would mean I am doing something wrong in the last part of my code. Where I add 4 values to i through the whole song. What would the code then be to add all 53968897 bytes into a 2d array? I read your link about the mp3 header thing, but I cant seem to understand and apply that information. I have tried to google an answer, but I cant seem to find any.

Comment: @Johnsen.Martin I don't know how else to convey to you that *if* the MP3 is being decoded by the underlying system, the fact that it came from MP3 is totally irrelevant after that fact.  I don't know what format your class decodes audio into, but we know it's signed and 16-bit.  Little-endian is most common.  Interleaved channels is most common.  So, the first two bytes are probably a little-endian 16-bit signed sample for channel 0.  The next two bytes are for channel 1.  Then, the next, channel 0.  Channel 1.  etc.

Comment: @Brad aaaaah, and then I skip i three times such that every array[i+4][4] is the 4 frequencies that represents the music, the 2 first for channel0 and the last 2 for channel1. This calculation matches datablock header in this article http://id3.org/mp3Frame

Comment: @Johnsen.Martin No!  What you're saying is not remotely accurate.  PCM samples don't contain frequency information... I already told you that and you already said you know that.  MP3 header data has absolutely no relevance once you've passed the MP3 through the codec.  It won't exist anymore.  I don't know what else to tell you other than read what I already wrote to you above.

Comment: @Brad I dont know if I actually go through a codec, I might just be getting the raw samples of my mp3. When I only read every fourth i value I get the audio data ranging from 0 to 255 like this https://i.imgur.com/1HMYAXQ.png, but when doing this most of the beginning is distorted where I get huge chunks of only 255, or only 0s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Brad and VC.One for making me realize my own mistakes.
To begin with I had to add the correct values to the PCM-signed encoding like this:

```
AudioFormat decodedFormat = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,
            (float)44.1,       //samplerate
            16,                //sampleSizeInBits
            2,                 //channels
            626,               //frameSize
            (float)38.4615385, //frameRate
            false);            //bigEndian
```

Then I needed to accurately represent the 2 channels in an array. How I did it above in the class AnalyzeMP3 is wrong, and it should be added like this:

```
    //adds 4 values to i through the whole song
    int[][] offset  = new int[mp3.getBytes().size()/4][4];
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < mp3.getBytes().size()/4;i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            offset[i][j] = mp3.getBytes().get(counter);
            counter++;
        }

    }
```

After making these changes the array is 4351104 in size. 4351104 / 44100 is equal to the song length in seconds. And there is no header or anything I have to skip, the array is now an accurate representation of the whole song with 44100 frequencies each second. Which can easily be transformed to represent 10ms as 441 frequencies, etc.